# Get keychain item without requiring a password in the confirmation prompt

Tags: macos, keychain

I've primarily seen two types of keychain prompts on macOS, one that requires a password and one that does not. In either case, the user is asked to confirm: "Always Allow", "Deny", or "Allow".

I am storing a password on the behalf of a user, so it seems silly to require the user to enter a password so I can get their other password…

What do I need to do to *not* require a password from the user when retrieving an item from a keychain (presuming the keychain is already unlocked, of course)? i.e. I want the user to know I'm retrieving the password, but only be required to confirm the action.

Do I need to `SecAddItem` a different way? Do I need to use the `SecItemCopyMatching` API a specific way? Does my application need to be signed (if so, is self-signing sufficient for testing)?